# Jmeter doesnt record intranet site

Tags: jmeter, record, intranet

I have a trouble here with Jmeter.
I am new with Jmeter.
I tried to record our company intranet site with Jmeter, but nothing recorded.
If I change website to other website, it worked.
Can anyone suggest me what to be set?

Or Jmeter doesn't support intranet recording?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Of course JMeter supports intranet site recording provided it is standard Http.

Check you Browser proxy configuration for internal site and configure correctly these for jmeter:
See command line options:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html